# Can applications developed in IBM Worklight be packaged using PhoneGap Build?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap-build

I am looking at an IDE to use to produce a hybrid app (at the moment for iOS and Android). Before finding out about Worklight, I was going to use NetBeans to develop the app then build it with PhoneGap, but Worklight appears to be such a powerful tool that I'd like to give it a shot. I'm just curious as to whether or not I could still use PhoneGap Build to produce the packaged applications once I've finished developing them in Worklight. (IMO it's much easier if I can deploy it to multiple devices at once rather than needed all the different IDEs and SDKs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PhongeGap Build with Worklight. Worklight projects require a certain structure that is not fully inline with that of a pure Cordova application.

Note that a Worklight Hybrid application, once generated by the Worklight build engine, already contains a version of Cordova built-in (in Worklight 6.2 this is currently Cordova v3.4; this version cannot be interchanged with another at this time).